# Make every Unicode character on a web page the same width

Tags: html, unicode, fonts

I need two following Unicode characters to have the same width in a web page: ▼ (&#9660;) and ▶ (&#9654;)

`font-family: monospace;`  does not help, they still get different width (Windows 8, Firefox 17):

[image: Screenshot showing monospace problem]

Is there any way to let every (and not only usual letters) character on a page to have the same width?

Source code of the example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>7
  <body>
    <h1 style="font-family: monospace;">
      &#9660;test 
      <br>
      &#9654;test
    </h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put both characters in another tag (like `<span>`) and give it a fixed width using CSS. Like this ([working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jhogervorst/FaUMJ/)):

```
<span style="display: inline-block; width: 30px;">&#9660;</span>test 
<br>
<span style="display: inline-block; width: 30px;">&#9654;</span>test
```

---

Or choose a CSS only approach which I assume would be more decent ([working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jhogervorst/Eyc4X/)):

```
<span class="opened">test</span>
<br>
<span class="closed">test</span>
```

And the CSS code:

```
.opened::before {
    display: inline-block;
    content: "▼";
    width: 30px;
}

.closed::before {
    display: inline-block;
    content: "▶";
    width: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! One small additional question: Will `width: 1em` make it scalable (for displays with a different density)?

Comment: You were right thinking that I am building kind of tree with nodes being opened and closed. The trick with "before" selector was helpful too:-) Also I found out that the character  ► (&#9658;) fits even better than ▶ (&#9654;).

Comment: @Andrej I'm not sure what you mean by display density, however, if you specify a width in `em`'s it'll get wider when you set a larger `font-size`. Here's [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/jhogervorst/yeAHK/) width a width of `2em`.

Comment: I meant smartphones with higher DPI. Your last example with "2em" demonstrates the right behavior - space, that special characters take, scales together with the font size.

Comment: Sizes for high DPI screens, like Retina screens in Apple's devices, are often automatically calculated. If I specify a width of 30px for an object and I open the page on my iPhone or iPad with a Retina display, the content is shown by 60 dots on the screen. You can read more about high resolution content on Apple devices [here](https://developer.apple.com/resources/high-resolution/).

Comment: @Andrej Yes, you should use `em`, `pt` or some unit other than pixels. `px` should generally only be used when you need to match something fundamentally measured in pixels, like a bitmap image.